# how to install collections in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to install a library of collections, a module сounter and defaultdict.
I have python 3.6 and Win 7 64x installed. When installing the "pip install collections" library, an error appears. "The version that satisfies the requirement sets could not be found".
How to fix this problem?

Comment: `collections` is a built in module, there is no need to install it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Collections module is a built-in module and comes with a base installation of Python, both for Python 2 and Python 3, and therefore doesn't need to be installed (and will not be found on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)). You can find a list of these modules [here](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html)